# Dynamic where clause based on table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to form a dynamic where clause based on the table. If same column present **'OR'** clause has to be added else it has to be **'AND'**. I am not achieve this because when same columns present it is not working

[image]

**Result**:

```
   Where = ((COL1='8715') OR (COL1 ='4100)) and ((COL2 BETWEEN 10 AND 20 ) OR (COL2 >=5))
```

**code:**

```
 lv_set := 'OR'

 FOR i in 1..:lv_count
 

  DO
         if (:OPERATOR[:i] = 'EQ')
           then
                 
                lv_where =  '(' || lv_where || :FIELD[:i] || ' = ' || :LOW[:i] || ')' || :lv_set;
                
         elseif (:OPERATOR[:i] = 'BT')
           then
                lv_where = lv_where || '('  ||  :FIELD[:i] || ' BETWEEN ' || :LOW[:i] || ' AND ' || :HIGH[i] || ')' || :lv_set; 
         
         elseif (:OPERATOR[:i] = 'LT')
           then
                lv_where = lv_where || '(' || :FIELD[:i] || ' < ' || :LOW[:i] || ')' || :lv_set;
         
         elseif (:OPERATOR[:i] = 'GT')
           then
                lv_where = lv_where || '(' || :FIELD[:i] || ' > ' || :LOW[:i] || ')' || :lv_set;
         
         elseif (:OPERATOR[:i] = 'LE')
           then
                lv_where = lv_where || '(' || :FIELD[:i] || ' <= ' || :LOW[:i] || ')' || :lv_set;
         
         elseif (:OPERATOR[:i] = 'GE')
           then
                lv_where =  lv_where || '(' || :FIELD[:i] || ' >= ' || :LOW[:i] || ')' || :lv_set;
         
         end if; 
         
      END FOR;
```

Comment: This is insane. I hope you are not working in an organization where they (or you) do such things in production. There is zero chance that you (and your team) caan use this data model correctly in all situations. Won't even try to touch this.

Answer (score 0):

Create variable as:

```
v_query VARCHAR2(4000);
v_where varchar2(2000);
```

Make your query:

```
v_query := 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ' || v_where
```

The **v_where** must contain characters and you have to make a logic which create a different query depending on your requirements.

Finally just you need to do:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query;
```

Al that statements must be defined into Block.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm